# Is there any algorithm that can automatically detect the rows and columns of sprite sheets？

Tags: algorithm, sprite

[image: sprite sheet sample]

Is there any algorithm that can automatically detect the rows and columns of sprite sheets like the one above? To make it easier for me to know the size and position of each grid for the animation display.

Comment: Even as a human I would say it could be 8 columns and 6 rows or 4 columns and 3 rows or ... . Without context you can only hope for educated guesses (like the border of a sprite should be transparent, The width should be a integer devider of the image with ...)

Comment: If a human provides number of rows and columns it's easy to calculate size and position.

Comment: @MrSmith42 Thanks for the reminder, you are right, it is true that in some cases it is not possible to get accurate results, but this is just a small function to assist the user, if there is a discrepancy with what the user thinks can also be changed by themselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! This is an ideal use case for the Fourier transform. If you squish the image down to 1 pixel height, take just the alpha channel, and do a Fourier transform on it, you will see a frequency peak at a wavelength corresponding to the number of pixels per sprite. You can do the same thing vertically. This will be robust even with closely packed sprites, as long as they have some amount of outline to extract.

If the sprites have irregular width/height but are separated by transparent regions and are in distinct bounding boxes, you can instead pick a random non-transparent pixel and greedily grow a bounding  box outward from it until the bounding box has only transient pixels at its outline, and then mark those pixels as “visited” and do the same with an unvisited pixels until you’ve visited all non-transparent pixels.

Comment: You've provided me with good ideas, and I think that even if these images don't have clear transparent borders, they still can be processed by separating the colors into two categories